# how to get another page session value in laravel 5.0?

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-5

I have set the session variable in `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php` file and this value is get in My controller using `Session:all()` laravel default function.

So, on that controller is it not display but on the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php` page, it displays.

The following is my AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php page code:

```
    use Session ;

    ......

    if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
    {
        session()->regenerate();
        Sesstion::put('admin','admin');
        session(['key' => 'value']);
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
                ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
                ->withErrors([
                    'email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
                ]);
   ......
```

and following is my controller code.

```
  use Session;

    ..........       

  public function index()
  {
    session()->regenerate();
    dd(Session::all());exit;
    return view('/admin/index');   
  }
  .......
```

Comment: some time's it give FatalErrorException Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Sesstion' not found

Comment: That's because you spelled Session wrong. It's Session not SessTion.

Comment: sometimes it is best to read the error carefully. like da vinci code, the solution is also inside the puzzle :)

Comment: @AndreiP. it's just typing mistake still is not work

Answer (score 0):

remove `session()->regenerate();` from controller code